# PHP use function as return;?

Tags: php, php-include

I'm using `include();` to load certain parts of my page, but sometimes if I'm working on a specific area I want the `include();` function to terminate somewhere within that included file, so I use `return;` and everything following that line will not be included when `include();` is called on that file. I can't use `die();` because sometimes I have other files needed to be included as well.

Now, I want to be able to control that `return;` function in terms of what other users see, for instance - I'd like to limit what types of users can see beyond that `return;` line within the included file. I want admin level users to be able to see beyond that point but not regular users. So I use some kind of `if() { }` statement to check the user type. Sometimes I want only myself to be able to view the content after the `return;` line, and I then add `if($ip != $my_ip) return;`.

The problem is that I have to manually write this stuff, but since I use it often I'd like to write a function that I can pass to what users I want to let bypass the `return;` part. So I setup a `terminate();` function, something like this:

```
function terminate($param) {
    // if statement 
    {
       return;
    }
}
```

But the `return;` line in that function only returns within that function, it doesn't have any effect on the file that called that function. So in other words, the `return;` line in my `terminate();` function won't actually do the `return;` I need to stop the `include();` function going beyond it.

So how do I stop the `include();` command on my file going beyond a certain point with a **function** and have it not interrupt the remaining code after stopping an `include();`?

**Edit:** as a temp fix, I'm using this:

```
if(terminate($param)) return;
```

So after passing my parameters to the function if it returns `true` (stop the `include();`), it will `return;` on the file I'm including. So it works that way, I'm just wondering if it's possible to just have a `terminate($param);` command that will fire the `return;` command on the file that called that function without having to wrap it around in an `if()` statement?..

Comment: `include` is an operation. For me it should be atomic - i.e. like any other operation it can only fail or success. And success means "included completely". Middle case seems to be odd at best, it's like "may be it was included" or "it was included, but we don't know how completely it was" (and for external script condition for "may be" is completely black box). So why do you need such behavior?

Comment: Aaah. I see. Then I can't imagine any other way than testing. You can write a lot of functions which check userTypes, Ip's etc, which returns boolean. `if(myFuncForUserTypes($user_id)) { // included content }`

Comment: My goal is to stop the `include();` **within** that file, not wether I want to include the file or not. It works with `return;`, but it's tedious writing conditions every time I want to terminate before a certain part of that include file, it would be much easier with a function. Also wrapping content `if()` blocks every time is also tedious.. I'm looking for a way to have the `return;` line within a function initiate that `return;` on the file that called the function, not have it only return **within** that called function.

Comment: @Alma Do - I've explained in my question the need for a termination. Certain parts of the included file are not meant to be viewed by all users, only certain groups. It has to do with developement - I don't want regular users to see parts that are being fixed or something, so as a temporary blockage I add the `return;` command to stop the `include();` function at that point, but also having conditions that the content after the `return;` would be visible to admins or just devs. It's a temp thing, so I don't want to go around placing `if()` blocks when I really just need a `return;` command

Comment: Normal web projects use conditions inwithin the template, which is not considered bad practice, PHP is templating language. It's good practice to write `<?php if ($app->UserController->hasPermissions($_SESSION['user_id'])):?> <p> some content</p> <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Yes but it starts getting messy with these `if()` blocks. As I've stated, it's meant for a temp block, if there is a problem - hide it from public view and have it visible to only the person fixing it or a certain group. Time is just wasted with these `if()` blocks, when the `return;` command does the trick of halting the `include();` at a necessary point. Writing these `if()` blocks takes time if I use `return;` or not, the goal is to have a function that can terminate without messing up the entire system like `die();` or `exit;`. And `return;` stops the include cleanly, so it works.

Comment: It seems for like you want to make code unmanagable for any other designer, developer, etc? I don't see a situation where if you have Table with 5 columns, and you want to hide the middle one, you will manage to do it with single function, it will stop the include after the middle column, but it will not output the 4th and 5th columns too. I provided you a suggestion with output buffer. But still for multiple conditions you will need to wrap the visible/nonvisible area

Answer (score 0):

In general, most of the modern projects, which are trying to use clean templates with only HTML, that are obeying the MVC architecture, etc, are using conditions in their templates. There's nothing wrong in it. If you are template looks clean.

```
<div class="content">
    <span class="subcontent"> some content </span>
    <?php if ($app->UserController->hasPermissions($_SESSION['id'])): ?>
        <span class="admincontent"> Admin Content </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This kind of code is considered OK. Your view DO have conditions and loops. You cannot avoid them. Also it does not look that clean if you have

```
<div class="content">
    <span class="subcontent"> some content </span>
    someFunction();
        <span class="admincontent"> Admin Content </span>
</div>
```

Which will also hide all the content till the end of the file. And it's hard to manage it. It's not impossible still. You can use output buffer for that:

Let's say you have:

**functions.php**

```
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1; //fictive session code ?>
<?php
function hasPermissions() {
    if ($_SESSION['user_id'] != 1) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }
}
?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

**end.php**

```
<?php $ob = ob_get_contents();?>
<?php ob_end_clean(); ?>
<?= $ob; ?>
```

**Template.php**

```
<?php include("functions.php"); ?>

<p>included content</p>
<?php hasPermissions(); ?>
<p> included content 2 </p>

<?php include("end.php"); ?>
```

so, if you are with session id = 1, and running **Template.php** file, the output will be:

```
included content

included content 2
```

Else it will output

```
included content
```